# to draw line with the intersection of circle in Android

Tags: android, geometry, zooming, line

I'm newbie, developing an android app to draw line dynamically.

With the intersection of circle I'll get coordinates. Using that points I'll draw line to connect all intersection points. Finally I'll connect last point with starting point.

To do this I tried to draw in mapview,Graphview,achartEngine. Nothing helped me. In mapview the line is drawn but it disappears for zooming. How to draw line in mapview without projecting to screen? Then only I'll get my coordinates correct. In Graphview decreasing X-axis crashes the app. In achartEngine it doesn't draws right I required.

Give some tips. In android, which feature provide this facility. In which view I want to draw or implement this logic to get perfection. It helps me lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add some code. so we know where u stopped at

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401811/draw-circle-on-mapview-without-using-the-device-coordinates

Comment: I used loop which suits my need